# I need to insert/update a row on a firebird table

Tags: sql, firebird

I need to update a single row on a table

table name = `TB_EST_PRODUTO` row `COD_BENEF`

I need to insert the code `'PR810000'` where on `TB_EST_PRODUTO CST = 040`
but I have no idea how to do it

Comment: What have you tried? What db, version you are using?

Comment: firebird 2.5 and i din't try anything yet.

Comment: Do you need to insert or do you need to update existing data? Please provide the DDL (or at least the structure), sample data and expected result. Also consider following a basic SQL tutorial.

Comment: you need to start with SQL tutorials for basolute novices, somethiong like that series "xxx for dummies" or "xxx in 2 weeks", and that is *for starters*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for... a simple `UPDATE` query, like so?

```
UPDATE TB_EST_PRODUTO SET COD_BENEF = 'PR810000' WHERE TB_EST_PRODUTO CST = 040
```

Comment: yep, i like simple things

Comment: Hi passing to say it worked. ty very much, you realy saved my day